# Vertical scrollBar not visible in dataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility property is Auto in DataGrid and MaxHeight is fixed, but scrollbar is not visible when height of row is more.

```
<DataGrid  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding   CM.SupportMessagesList}" CanUserAddRows="False" 
  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Transparent" 
  VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent" MaxHeight="400" Height="400"  
  IsReadOnly="True" Background="White" AreRowDetailsFrozen="False" 
  RowHeaderWidth="0" ColumnHeaderHeight="0">
```

Comment: can you post ur xaml